# Include an external javascript file in an SSRS report

Tags: javascript, sql-server, reporting-services, vbscript

I have a number of SSRS reports that will benefit from some simple javascript.

I know I can write inline javascript in SSRS, but how can I get the report engine to insert a script tag like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js" />
```

I have checked [Is it possible to embed javascript into an SSRS Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789303/is-it-possible-to-embed-javascript-into-an-ssrs-report) and a few blogs, and I'm sure it is easily done.

I expect it will need to be done with VBscript but I don't know where to start. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm sure it is easily done.

I was wrong. Not easy. SSRS is not pleasant to extend; if you need an interactive report, you should investigate using a different framework